# How to run java program using Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to run a Java project using Maven, need help on how to run

I tried with various options, Run As > Maven clean, Run As > Maven Install, Run As > Maven test, etc. 
But the output is not showing in the console though build is successful

I am using eclipse and able to run java file using Run As > Java Application

My Build tag in pom.xml

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
             <mainClass>mypackage.classnamehavingmain</mainClass>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
```

Comment: Maven is a build tool. It compiles the classes, finds the dependencies, makes a JAR. It doesn't run anything except a suite of tests. You don't run your app via Maven.

Comment: Thank you 

 Thank you @Michael But I have added an execution plugin in my pom.xml and expecting the java program to run? Is my understanding wrong, Ref: https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Not familiar with the plugin, but you have not specified any executions (i.e. the plugin will do nothing). Take a look at their configuration https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html and copy where appropriate. Running in Maven sounds like a hack though, even if a plugin makes it possible.

Answer (score 7):

You should add the goal for execution

```xml
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>your_goal_name</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

and then to execute you can perform :

```
 mvn exec:your_goal_name
```

Comment: Adding  phase and goal solved my problem   <execution>
              <phase>test</phase>  
              <goals>
               <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to run it from the terminal you can do `mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=mypackage.classnamehavingmain`.